# Woocommerce product category has a missing display tab

Tags: woocommerce, product, display, missing-features

In Woocommerce when I go to WooCommerce > Settings > Products, there should be tab called Display.
For me it's missing, as shown in the attached screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFeWZ.png)

Am I missing something, or can is this tab disabled from somewhere ?

Comment: Can be found at Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce since WooCommerce 3.3.0 (2018-01-30)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under Appearance > Customize > Woocommerce.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).